# How to get $route and $router in Nuxt SSR middleware?

Tags: nuxt.js, middleware, router

I have a Nuxt application with the page component which contains the middleware. This middleware should get query string parameter then make a call to API and then redirect to new location. Middleware looks like:

```
async middleware(context) {
    if (!context.$route.query.token)
    {
        const result = await context.$api.campaigns.createNewShare();
        context.$router.push({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
    }
},
```

The problem is that router and route are undefined. How to get this objects in middleware?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand how and why but this works:

```
async middleware(context) {
    if (!context.route.query.token)
    {
        const result = await context.$api.campaigns.createNewShare();
        context.redirect({'name': 'campaigns-new', 'query': {token: result.data.token}});
    }
},
```

Comment: The various properties of Nuxt's `context` object can be found @ https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/